# error writing Lambda function to insert record to DynamoDB table

Tags: lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and Lambda. I created a test aws account and in DynamoDB created a table called guestbook with fields data and message. I tried the below code to insert record into table using lambda function.

and when I try to test this function, its giving this error

> {   "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function'" }

Can someone help me understand what is going wrong here.

FYI, I copied the code from example on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_-aEXmluq8&index=7&list=PLzvRQMJ9HDiSQMe68cti8cupI0mzLk1Gc) .

Here is the code.

```
console.log('Starting Function');

const AWS = require ('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'us-west-1' });
exports.handle = function (e, ctx, callback) {

    var params = {
        item: {
            date: Date.now(),
            message: "this is test"
        },
        TableName: 'guestbook'
    };

    docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
       if (err) {
           callback(err, null);
       } else {
           callback(null, data);
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The params was incorrect. The api's guide is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#put-property).
The correct params should be like this.

```
console.log('Starting Function');
const AWS = require ('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-west-1'});
exports.handle = function (e,ctx, callback){


var params = {
    TableName: 'guestbook'
    Item: {
        date: Date.now(),
        message: "this is test"
    }
 }

 docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
     } else {
        callback(null,data);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thx popoi, I am still getting the same error output. But I noticed under logout that it says "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 2) ".

Comment: Your Lambda is running in Python runtime but the code is for NodeJs. So for the code to run, you might want to run it using NodeJs 4.3 Runtime Enviroment that you can preselect during creating Lmbda function

Comment: I correct as you suggested. Now I am getting error "Task timed out after 3.00 seconds" what must be wrong this time?

Comment: I increased the timeout to 15 seconds and still getting "Task timed out after 15.00 seconds"